# Is there a preprocessor Macro i can check to see if arc4random is available?

Tags: c++, openbsd

Windows doesn't seem to support arc4random. Is there a preprocessor macro I can use to identify if arc4random is supported by the platform I'm compiling for ?

https://man.openbsd.org/arc4random.3

Comment: #if WINDOWS ?..

Comment: Not part of the C or C++ Standard library. Don't think it's part of POSIX either. Support is likely to be spotty.

Comment: What are you going to do if it's not there? And, if there's a suitable approach when it's not there, why not use that approach even if it **is** there?

Comment: @PeteBecker Well, since it looks like Windows is the only platform in common use that doesn't provide this function (Linux has it, and macOS, being BSD-based, also has it, for example), using [`BCryptGenRandom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom) should provide a working solution - on Windows and Windows only.  Other than that, what are the options?  Presumably, `<random>` does not satisfy the OP or he would not be looking elsewhere.

Comment: @PaulSanders — you **might** be right, but the point of my comment was to encourage the poster to expand the question, not to solicit people’s guesses.

Comment: @PeteBecker I guess the question is a bit bare, yes.  But your comment was a bit too oblique to me to figure out what you really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/arc4random) says it's from `<bsd/stdlib.h>`, so...

```
#if __has_include(<bsd/stdlib.h>)
```

Comment: Hmmm, maybe, that page is for Linux.  According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html), macOS, for example, declares it in `stdlib.h`, although that page is very old and maybe they have moved it to 'conform'.  But knowing Apple, probably not.  If the OP cares (doubtful!), he would have to check.